# 遷移された子画面でリスト選択された値を、親画面のあるテキストボックスへ戻したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

親画面に動的で生成されるテーブルが存在しています（初期表示は10行）。初期表示の各行には行追加ボタンがあって、行を無限に増やすことができます。
また、各行のある列にはinputタグのテキストボックスを構成していますが、nameだけが割り当てられているだけで、どの行もclass・id双方が設定されていない状態です。

window.openで開く子画面は、上記テーブルの各行にイメージボタンも配置されるので、この押下をもって開くようにしています。【この隣の要素】=テキストボックスへ、子画面側リストボックスで選択されたvalを戻したいと考えています。インターネット上の記事を見よう見まねで、現況以下コーディングになっています。
（検証のための行を追加しています）

【親画面のJS】

```
// 品名コード検索画面（winOpenとセットで利用）
$(document).on("click", ".cdsrch", function(e) {
    // **** 戻ってくるテキストボックス特定のため、IDに99を付与
    $(this).next().attr("id","99");
    console.log($(this).next().prop("tagName")+"⇒"+$(this).next().prop("id"));
    // ****
    winOpen("cdselect0.php", 600, 960);
    return false;
});
```

【子画面のJS】

```
//生成された品名コードのリストボックスで更に指定を受けたら．．．
$("[name=car_model]").on("change", function(){
　　　　var selectval = $(".car_model option:selected").val();
//　　window.opener.document.getElementById("99").val(selectval);
　　　　alert (selectval);
　　　　alert (window.opener.document.getElementById("99").prop("tagName"));
　　　　close();
});

function winOpen(url, width, height) {
　　　　if (width > 800) {
　　　　　　　　width = 800;
　　　　}
　　　　if (height > 600) {
　　　　　　　　height = 600;
　　　　}
　　　　window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=' + width + ', height=' + height);
}
```

子画面側のJSがコけているのか、親画面に値が渡らないばかりか子画面のcloseも行われません。（案の定エラーになっている様子↓の図）

子画面側でID=99の要素を取得できない要因、解決策についてご支援を頂けませんでしょうか？？

開発ツールというものを初めて使い始めていますが、親画面のコンソールを見た限り、子画面を開く際に一応呼びもとのタグに99のID付与は成功しているようです。
但し、子画面側で親画面のID=99のタグを見つけられない状況が起きているような気がします。

画像を貼り付けさせていただきます。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 子画面を開くのに`winOpen`という関数を利用しているようですが、自作でしょうか? そうであれば合わせて記載した方がよいと思います。

Comment: user20098様　ご見解をありがとうございます。漏れていることに気がつきませんでした。助かります！

Comment: $(this).next().attr('id','99');で、子画面から値の戻される要素を指定できるようにしているつもりですが、これが作用していない？？

Comment: 質問文を見る限り、期待通り動作するように見えます。(`$(this).next()`はイベント対象要素の次の要素であるし、`window.opener`は同一ドメインのアクセスなので参照できる) ページ全体のどこかに問題があるように予想しますので「開発者ツール」で親ページを確認するのがよいかと思います。

Comment: user20098様　貴重なご見解まことにありがとうございます。集中してデバッグに励めるのでこういったご見解でも非常に助かります。暫く回答が付かなかったので非常識な問い合わせをしているのでは？と不安がありました。重ねて御礼申し上げます。

Comment: 本文に検証中のコーディングを分かるよう画像を追加しました。

Comment: `alert(window.opener.document.getElementById("99"))` だとどうなります？

Comment: shingo.nakanishi様　ご見解ありがとうございました。ご提示のalert、早速ためさせて頂きました。[object HTMLInputElemntと表示され、エラーにならない状態です。皆様のご支援でなんとか前進しそうです。それといい忘れました。コードを表示し易くしてもらったこと感謝です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のように修正するとエラーが消えませんか？

```
$("[name=car_model]").on("change", function(){
　　　　var selectval = $(".car_model option:selected").val();
//　　window.opener.document.getElementById("99").val(selectval);
　　　　var elem = window.opener.document.getElementById("99");
　　　　alert (selectval);
　　　　alert ($(elem).prop("tagName"));
　　　　close();
});
```

getElementByIdがDOMの要素を取得するだけでjQueryオブジェクトになっていないためにpropにアクセス失敗しているだけな気がします。
とんちんかんな答えだったらすみません。

Comment: 無事解決したようでよかったです。

Comment: user17014様　無事にタグ拾ってこれました。ありがとうございます。これは大きな前進です。取り急ぎ経過報告とお礼まで