# 子画面から親画面の値格納、TEXT枠は成功したが直近のLabelへ値が戻らない・表示されない？

Tags: javascript, jquery

本件は案件№：38680[「遷移された子画面でリスト選択された値を、～」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38680/)の続きです．．．
先の件、お蔭様で親画面側のテキストボックスにID付与・除去を果たすことで、目的の行（テーブル内のテキスト枠）へリストの選択値を戻すことを成功しています。

今回はテキスト枠と同行にある隣のLabelへ、リスト選択された表示内容を戻したいと思っています。
些細な原因とも思うわけですが、Labelということが影響しているのか、同行隣という要素の取得に失敗している要因かで、目的を達成できません。
（動的に生成されるTABLE=HTMLを、開発ツールで見ることってできない？？）

JSの開発が初めて間もなく、デバッグが不慣れのため掲載してしまいました。
お手すきの方ございましたら、解決に向けたご支援をよろしくお願い致します。

```
// ★子画面ＪＳ★　品名コードのリストボックスで指定を受けたら．．．
$("[name=car_model]").on("change", function(){
    // 親画面コード枠（TEXT）は、選択リストボックスの値を戻す
    var cd = $(".car_model option:selected").val();

    // 親画面名称枠（LABEL）は、選択リストボックスの表示内容を戻す
    var totalval = $(".car_model option:selected").text()
    var strtext = totalval.split("　　　");
    var name = strtext[1];
    alert(name);    // ←表示できた！！！

    // こちらは成功している
    var elem = window.opener.document.getElementById("99");
　　　 $(elem).val(cd);

    // こちらが成功しない　***********************
    $(elem).closest("label").innerHTML = name;
    $(elem).closest("label").css("width", "20px");  //　まさか隠れてる、とか思って
    //********************************************

    //　親画面の指示行のID属性を除去し、当該子画面を閉じる
    $(elem).removeAttr("id");
    close();
});

// ★親画面ＪＳ★　品名コード検索画面（winOpenとセットで利用）
$(document).on("click", ".cdsrch", function(e) {
    // **** 戻ってくるテキストボックス特定のため、IDに99を付与
    $(this).next().attr("id","99");
    // ****
    winOpen("cdselect0.php", 600, 960);
    return false;
});
function winOpen(url, width, height) {
    if (width > 800) {
        width = 800;
    }
    if (height > 600) {
        height = 600;
    }
    window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=" + width + ", height=" + height);
}
<!--★★親画面HTML-->
<table>
    <tr class="appLineDummy">
        <td><button class="cdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png"></button>
            <input type="text" name="cd" style="width:45px;"></td>
        <td><label name="name"></label></td>
        <td><label name="capa"></label></td>
        <td><label name="scond"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 親画面のHTMLはどのようになっていますか？コードを見る限り<label><input id="99"></label>のような構造になっているということでしょうか？

Comment: 皆様　ご確認ありがとうございます。本文にHTMLを追記しました。
親画面のイメージボタン押下（テーブルの行上の）で子画面が開かれるのですが、この際
親画面側にフィードバックを期待するINPUT　type=TEXTにのみ、一時的なIDを付与しています。
この隣のラベルにも、子画面で取得した内容（選択リストボックスの表示内容抜粋部分）を
フィードバックしたいと考えています。
引き続きよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

labelへの指定が曖昧なので、ID指定での代入と親ＨＴＭＬの構造から　以下のスクリプトを書きました。

```js
$(function(){
    var cd = "001";
    var name = "name001";

//    var elem = document.getElementById("99");
//    $(elem).val(cd);
//上の２行は、jqueryで 以下の様にも書ける
$("#99").val(cd);
//window.opener.$("#99").val(cd);

//ID位置から２親戻って　trの配下のlabelを探す。
var label = $("#99").parent().parent().find("label");
//var label = window.opener.$("#99").parent().parent().find("label");


//labelが複数なのでeq(index)で指定する。
//$("#99").parent().parent().find("label").eq(0).html(name); と書いても良いが、毎回labelを探すので構造が大きくなると遅くなる。
    label.eq(0).html(name); //name
    label.eq(1).html("capa"); //capa
    label.eq(2).html("scond"); //scond
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="appLineDummy">
        <td><button class="cdsrch" type="button"><img width="30" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ja/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=1cfb10b305ca"></button>
            <input type="text" name="cd" style="width:45px;" id="99"></td>
        <td><label name="name">xxx</label></td>
        <td><label name="capa"></label></td>
        <td><label name="scond"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="appLineDummy">
        <td><button class="cdsrch" type="button"><img width="30" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ja/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=1cfb10b305ca"></button>
            <input type="text" name="cd" style="width:45px;"></td>
        <td><label name="name">yyy</label></td>
        <td><label name="capa"></label></td>
        <td><label name="scond"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yyz様　ご丁寧な事例のご提示誠にありがとうございます。本当にど素人で申し訳ありません、ご提案の方式を採用する場合、
以下の部分に、【親画面側の】という修飾詞が必要になるのかな？と思いました。認識が正しい場合、その方法を教えて下さいませんか？
試しにそのまんま貼り付けたら、親画面のテキスト枠に値が戻らなくなったのでそう思いました。（IDでタグを見つけられないと、エラーで停まってしまう？？=子画面側の開発ツールを開いて確認するべきかな）    //    var elem = document.getElementById("99");
//    $(elem).val(cd);
//上の２行は、jqueryで 以下の様にも書ける
$("#99").val(cd);

Comment: window.openで開いた子windowから親をjqueryで操作するには、"window.opener.$('セレクタ').val();"　の様に　"window.opener."を付けると操作できます。

Comment: スニッペットにもコメントで追記しました。

Comment: yyz様　何から何まですみません、また、ありがとうございました。TRまで遡ってから探したらうまくいった、ということですかね。それともJavaScriptとJQueryがよく区別できていなかったことが原因？？

Comment: closestではｔｄの中だけ、parentsでは範囲が広すぎる、なのでparentを使いました。セレクタの指定を適切に行えばもっと単純に選択できると思います。　parent() : 1つ上の階層の要素を取得 closest() : セレクタに合致する、直近の階層の要素を取得　parents()　: 上の階層の全ての要素を取得
　　
JQu‌​eryは、JavaScriptの中で動いています、両方の使い方をもっと知ると良いかと思います。

Comment: yyz様　詳しい説明をありがとうございました。完璧に理解できました。

Answer (score 1):

$(elem).closest("label").innerHTML = name;
ではなく、
$(elem).closest("label").html(name);
でいかがでしょうか。

Comment: souz様　ご見解をありがとうございます。結果は変わりませんでした。本当みなさんのお手間をとらせて申し訳ないです。

Comment: souz様　yyz様のご回答を参考に正確に親画面側の要素を捉えられたとしても、innerHTMLではうまくラベルに値を表示できず、
ご教示頂きましたhtml()でしたら、うまく表示することができました。
お二方のご支援なしには達成することができませんでした。改めてお礼を述べさせて頂きます、ありがとうございました。